# Designing Django admin panel by tailwind

Tags: django, django-admin, tailwind-css

I hope you are fine.
I want to customize my django admin panel by tailwind. I know how to use tailwind in the templates of my django apps but unfortunately I am not able to use tailwind in the admin template and I have also tried multiple ways to solve this such as putting cdn in the admin base.hml or installing django-tailwind but all of them hasn’t worked for me yet.
I will thank if anyone who has experience about this matter give me a piece of guidance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The django-tailwind package is not for django admin customisation. The first step could be this package [django-admin-tailwind](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-tailwind/) from here, you can add some more code to the package to suit your needs, probably make a PR as well. Happy coding!

Comment: Excuse do you know a better way to customize django admin panel by tailwind?

Comment: Hey, if I dig into it I can manage to customize but I used the same package once.

Comment: Ok thanks I have installed the package and put the template folder inside the project templates directory and it is working but the problem is that my language is RTL and I need to customize it completely but the html files are very complicated to change and by the other hand I need the Django template tags inside it .Do you have any suggestions to know which file is for which page and what is the usage of those template tags to styling the admin panel by tailwind easier?

Comment: Hey, you can follow through. Each template has a folder, and you should be able to find the file you are looking for by checking a folder name. I can't mention the exact folders and file names really.

Comment: Hi again.Excuse me I have two questions that I will thank if you help me to solve them:

Comment: 1)I want to put a location field in a django model in admin that the admin can set a location and then the latitude and longtitude will be saved without using google map api.

Comment: 2)I have created a superuser in my django project that access to all of the permissions of the admin page. The problem is that when I add an object to the customized user model and set is_staff = true for that new user and then logout from the admin, I cannot login with the staff user account due to the error that says “please enter correct username and password for the staff acount” despite the matter that the username and password of that staff user are right.

Comment: Since the two question are not related to the question you asked here, you can ask them separately. Did you answer to your tailwind help?